# Build error - targeted OS version does not support use of thread local variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, google-cast-sdk

What does the below error means? I've never seen this before.

> d: targeted OS version does not support use of thread local variables
>   in __ZN12base_logging10LogMessage5FlushEv for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

I'm using cocoapod for google cast sdk and building in Xcode 10 beta and xcode 9.4.

Answer (score 39):

**Changing the deployment target to 9.0 worked for me**

open Xcode:

1. select YOUR_PROJECT_NAME from target
2. change Deployment target to 9.0 or greater under Deployment Info tab.

Hope it helps!

Edit: For visual/image reference

[image]

Comment: This didn't resolve my issue, any idea what might be the cause?

Comment: If you are using VS, open PLIST go to application and change deployment target.

Answer (score 25):

Your project tries to link some C++ code which makes use of a C++11 concept not supported all iOS platforms.

I think `thread_local` is allowed beginning with iOS 9. Try to set the deployment target to iOS 9 or later.

The offending code is in `base_logging::LogMessage::Flush()`.

Comment: Yeah you're right, this was the problem indeed. Changing the deployment target to iOS 9.0 solves the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Change the TARGET -> Your Project Name -> Deployment Info -> Deployment Target -> 9.0 solve the problem.... not working if you change the one under PROJECT

Comment: I'm having this with konan on Xcode 10 only, the same project on Xcode 9 builds fine... Changing the deployment target doesn't fix it for Xcode 10. A couple other solutions can be found in https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/2084 which are konan-specific

Comment: Rising deployment target is not a solution.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Maybe raising the deployment target is not an *option* for you but it definitely is a solution.

Answer (score 23):

[image]

Please change deployment target to 9.0 as shown in the image.